# Filter response in jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coffeescript, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to implement jQuery.autocomplete which I use to enter tags (much like here on SO). However, I don't want to show tags that I have already in my list. If I have added `foo` already I don't want it to show up as a suggestion. The list of tags are fetched from my server. However, I have some issues with altering the `ui.content` object.

I use the response method found [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response):

```
response: (event, ui)->
  # Fetch already added tags
  current = $('input#photo_tag_list').val().split(',')
  # Filter out already added tags from result
  ui.content = ui.content.filter (el) -> $.inArray(el.label, current) == -1
```

However, the above doesn't work. It still shows all tags. If I inspect ui.content I can see that it looks correct... Is the above async or something?!

The weird thing is that if I do:

```
ui.content.push({label: "Foo", value:"Bar"})
```

`Foo` shows up in the autocomplete list. But if I do this:

```
ui.content = []
```

It still shows everything returned. I would expect an empty list.

Why would this be? How do I modify the result list correctly?

**Update**
Got it to work based on Andrew Whitaker's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it based on Andrew Whitaker's answer.

Coffescript:

```
response: (event, ui)->
  current = $('input#photo_tag_list').val().split(',')
  for el, i in ui.content by -1
    if $.inArray(el.label, current) != -1
      ui.content.splice(i, 1)
```

Works great!

Comment: Looks like an excellent place to use lodash: http://lodash.com/docs. It's super effective.

Comment: Also, local style: if you get the solution based on someone else's answer, please update the question with an "Update:" section and reference the answer that helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the way JavaScript passes parameters. `ui.content` is a *copy of a reference* to an array. You cannot modify that reference and expect the results to be visible outside of the function. This is better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language).

For a simplified example, check this out:

```
function modify(item) {
    item.arr = [];
}

var obj = {
    text: 'hi',
    arr: [1,2,3,4]
};

modify(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9swwA/1/

The log statement will show that `obj.arr` is still `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. You essentially have the same problem.

---

So to get around this you can use `splice` to remove the items from the array. Unfortunately you're going to have to add a bit more code:

```
i = ui.content.length - 1

while i >= 0
  currentItem = ui.content[i]
  index = $.inArray(currentItem, current)
  ui.content.splice i, 1  if index is -1
  i--
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I tried something like that at first iterating from the end and slicing but never got it to work in coffeescript... I'll try again.

Comment: Also, in your solution you splice based on the wrong index. I managed to make it work now and posted the answer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that I didn't have a chance to test it. I'll update